# How to switch java Frames?

Tags: java

So i'm doing a school project based on a medical store (it's about plants). I have two classes(each has one JFrame).

Login:

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login extends JFrame{
JPanel panelLogin;
JTextField usernameField;
JPasswordField parolaField;
JButton butonLogin,butonCancel;

public JPanel createContentPane (){

    //Creez un panel pe care sa pun toate campurile.
    panelLogin = new JPanel();
    panelLogin.setLayout(null);
    panelLogin.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
    panelLogin.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login"));

    //usernameField
    usernameField = new JTextField();
    usernameField.setLocation(50, 50);
    usernameField.setSize(300, 25);
    usernameField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    //placeholder pt usernameField
    final String placeholderUsername = "Username";
    usernameField.setText(placeholderUsername);    
    usernameField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                        showingPlaceholder = false;
                        usernameField.setText("");
                }
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (usernameField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        usernameField.setText(placeholderUsername);
                        showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
        }
    });
    panelLogin.add(usernameField);

    //parolaField
    parolaField = new JPasswordField();
    parolaField.setLocation(50, 100);
    parolaField.setSize(300, 25);
    parolaField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    //placeholder pt parolaField
    final String placeholderParola = "Parola";
    parolaField.setText(placeholderParola);    
    parolaField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                        showingPlaceholder = false;
                        parolaField.setText("");
                }
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (parolaField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        parolaField.setText(placeholderParola);
                        showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
        }
    });       
    panelLogin.add(parolaField);

    //butonLogin
    butonLogin = new JButton("Login");
    butonLogin.setLocation(70, 140);
    butonLogin.setSize(100, 20);
    butonLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            butonLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            /*
            String uname=usernameField.getText();
            String pword=parolaField.getText();
            if(uname.equals("admin") && pword.equals("admin")){
                Home home=new Home();
                home.setVisible(true); 
                //this.dispose();
            }
            else{
            JFrame rootPane = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Username sau parola incorecte","Eroare la conectare",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }*/
        }
    });
    panelLogin.add(butonLogin);

    //butonCancel
    butonCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    butonCancel.setLocation(220, 140);
    butonCancel.setSize(100, 20);
    butonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    panelLogin.add(butonCancel);

    //Returnez panelul
    panelLogin.setOpaque(true);
    return panelLogin;
}

private static void LoginGUI() {

    JFrame frameLogin = new JFrame("PLAFAR * Calinescu George-Catalin * 221");

    //Creez panelul peste frame si il stilizez
    Login login = new Login();
    frameLogin.setContentPane(login.createContentPane()); 
    frameLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameLogin.setSize(400, 250);
    frameLogin.setVisible(true);
}
private void butonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String uname=usernameField.getText();
            String pword=parolaField.getText();
            if(uname.equals("admin") && pword.equals("admin")){
                Home ho=new Home();
                ho.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            else{
                JFrame rootPane = null;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Username sau parola incorecte","Eroare la conectare",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creez GUI si il afisez pe ecran
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            LoginGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}
and Home:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Home extends JFrame{
JPanel panelHome;
static String[] listaplante=new String[10];
static String[] listacantitati=new String[10];
static String[] listapreturi=new String[10];
static int kPlante=0, kCantitati=0, kPreturi=0;
JButton butonCumpara,butonAdauga;
JTextField cantitateField;


public JPanel createHomeContentPane (){

    //Creez un panel pe care sa pun toate campurile.
    panelHome = new JPanel();
    panelHome.setLayout(null);
    panelHome.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
    panelHome.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Home"));

    //Creez lista cu plante
    DefaultListModel<String> listaPlante = new DefaultListModel<>();  
    JList<String> list = new JList<>(citirePlante());  
    list.setBounds(50,100, 75,75); 
    panelHome.add(list);  

    //Creez lista cu cantitatile fiecarei plante
    DefaultListModel<String> listaCantitati = new DefaultListModel<>();  
    JList<String> list2 = new JList<>(citireCantitati());  
    list2.setBounds(150,100, 75,75); 
    panelHome.add(list2); 

    //Creez lista cu preturile fiecarei plante
    DefaultListModel<String> listaPreturi = new DefaultListModel<>();  
    JList<String> list3 = new JList<>(citirePreturi());  
    list3.setBounds(250,100, 75,75); 
    panelHome.add(list3); 

    //Creez titlurile pt fiecare lista
    JLabel denumireLabel=new JLabel("Denumire:");
    denumireLabel.setBounds(50,80,70,20);
    panelHome.add(denumireLabel);

    JLabel cantitatiLabel=new JLabel("Cantitati:");
    cantitatiLabel.setBounds(150,80,70,20);
    panelHome.add(cantitatiLabel);

    JLabel preturiLabel=new JLabel("Preturi:");
    preturiLabel.setBounds(250,80,70,20);
    panelHome.add(preturiLabel);

    //Creez un camp pt a adauga cantitatea dorita care urmeaza a fi cumparata
    //cantitateField
    cantitateField = new JTextField();
    cantitateField.setBounds(180,180,100,20);
    cantitateField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    //placeholder pt cantitateField
    final String placeholderCantitate = "Cantitatea dorita";
    cantitateField.setText(placeholderCantitate);    
    cantitateField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                        showingPlaceholder = false;
                        cantitateField.setText("");
                }
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (cantitateField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        cantitateField.setText(placeholderCantitate);
                        showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
        }
    });
    panelHome.add(cantitateField);


    //Butonul de cumparare
    butonCumpara = new JButton("Cumpara");
    butonCumpara.setLocation(180, 200);
    butonCumpara.setSize(100, 20);
    butonCumpara.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            String plantaselectata = list.getSelectedValue();
            int indexplanta=list.getSelectedIndex();
            String cantitateselectata = list2.getSelectedValue();
            int indexcantitate=list2.getSelectedIndex();
            String pretselectat = list3.getSelectedValue();
            int indexpret=list3.getSelectedIndex();
            String cantitatedorita=cantitateField.getText();

            int valCantitate=Integer.valueOf(cantitateselectata);
            int valCantitateDorita=Integer.valueOf(cantitatedorita);
            int valPret=Integer.valueOf(pretselectat);

            if(indexplanta==indexcantitate && indexplanta==indexpret){
                if(valCantitateDorita<=valCantitate){
                    try {
                        afisPlantaCumparata(plantaselectata,valCantitateDorita);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    int a=valCantitate-valCantitateDorita;
                    String b=Integer.toString(a);
                    listacantitati[indexcantitate]=b;
                    panelHome.setVisible(false);
                    panelHome.setVisible(true);
                }
                else{
                    JFrame rootPane = null;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Cantitatea nu esti disponibila","Eroare de cumparare",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            else{
                JFrame rootPane = null;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Planta, cantitate si pretul nu sunt din aceeasi categorie","Eroare de cumparare",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    });
    panelHome.add(butonCumpara);

    //Butonul de adaugare a unei plantei noi
    butonAdauga = new JButton("Adauga");
    butonAdauga.setLocation(80, 200);
    butonAdauga.setSize(100, 20);
    butonAdauga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("DsA");
        }
    });
    panelHome.add(butonAdauga);

    //Returnez panelul
    panelHome.setOpaque(true);
    return panelHome;
}

public static String[] citirePlante(){
    BufferedReader objReader = null;
    try {
        String strCurrentLine;
        objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Plante.txt"));
        while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
            listaplante[kPlante] = strCurrentLine;
            kPlante++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (objReader != null)
            objReader.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listaplante;
}

public static String[] citireCantitati(){
    BufferedReader objReader = null;
    try {
        String strCurrentLine;
        objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cantitati.txt"));
        while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
            listacantitati[kCantitati] = strCurrentLine;
            kCantitati++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (objReader != null)
            objReader.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listacantitati;
}

public static String[] citirePreturi(){
    BufferedReader objReader = null;
    try {
        String strCurrentLine;
        objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Preturi.txt"));
        while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
            listapreturi[kPreturi] = strCurrentLine;
            kPreturi++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (objReader != null)
            objReader.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listapreturi;
}

public static void afisPlantaCumparata(String p, int c) throws IOException{
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("PlanteVandute.txt");
 try (

         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {

        bw.write(p+" "+c+"\n");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    }
```

}

```
private static void HomeGUI() {

    JFrame frameHome = new JFrame("PLAFAR * Calinescu George-Catalin * 221");

    //Creez panelul peste frame si il stilizez
    Home home = new Home();
    frameHome.setContentPane(home.createHomeContentPane()); 
    frameHome.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameHome.setSize(400, 300);
    frameHome.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creez GUI si il afisez pe ecran
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            HomeGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

So i can't switch the frames when i login in with username admin and password admin. It's showing another frame that looks new to me, not my Home Frame. Why? what i did wrong?
And the other question is that: if i buy one plant i write into a text file the name and the amount that the buyer buyed but if i buy another one the file rewrites and i want to have all the plants that are buyed there. any typs?

Answer (score 0):

Why use two frames in the first place??

Just use single main JFrame.

set its layout to be CardLayout

create both Login and Home by extending JPanel.

place them in main frame and show Login or Home panel as required!!

[learn about CardLayout here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiP39-AlabmAhU0juYKHT-RAXYQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2Flayout%2Fcard.html&usg=AOvVaw2uzJB_4E6rgf0bO0ZNEATC)

Comment: because this is how i started, i'm new to java. anyway, i don't have much time to change the code now, i would like to stick to my code as much as possible

Comment: also i want to hide one when the other one is visible